# Time machine backup folders visible but not available

Tags: time-machine

A few days ago I saw in the Time Machine Preferences Pane that my Mac tried to clean up my TM disk for more space. After that the first backup shown there became a very recent day (previously it was the beginning of this year). Furthermore, after that cleanup I don't see much space being released on the disk, and now TM backup still fails due to "insufficient space."

But if I open the TM backup folder on the disk in Finder, I see backup folders all the way back to the beginning of this year, and they're not empty. Is there any way to make them available again?

Based on [this other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/391491/backups-not-available-in-time-machine-but-visible-in-disks-backupdb-folder), I've already tried

```sh
sudo mdfind "com_apple_backup_excludeItem = 'com.apple.backupd'" | grep -E "^$HOME/?\$"
```

and it's empty. I've also gone through the `mdfind` results myself and didn't notice anything suspicious.

I'm on macOS 10.15.7 (19H1323) with an encrypted HFS+ TM disk.

Comment: Have you tried, from disk utility, to do a SOS on the TM partition?

Comment: You must deactivate the automatic tm backup before doing first aid.

Comment: @Jean_JD I don't think automatic backup would interfere since first aid requires the disk to be unmounted?